# How do I set a state in a child component?

Tags: android, react-native, components, state

Let's say I have a component.

Inside that component I am calling a child component.

That child component has a state, which I would want to set from the parent component.

**Component**

```
// component
// ...

setState( 1 );

<ChildComponent ???setStateFunc={setState}???> // This setState should point to the child function

setState( 2 );

// ...
// end component
```

**Child component**

```
// child component
// ...

const [state, setState] = useState(null);

// ...
// end child component
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your Parent Component State should update from Child Component, handle your states like this:

Add this to your **Parent Component** File:

```js
this.state = {
    value: 0
}
...

changeHandler = (e) => {
   this.setState({value: e})
}

...

//Pass this function like this 
<ChildComponent value={{this.state.value}} setValue={(e) => changeHandler(e)}>
```

And manage your setValue by setting any value from your **Child Component** file, like:

```js
...

//For example if you're using TextInput component
<TextInput 
    value={this.props.value}
    onChangeText={this.props.setValue}
/>
...
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was not entirely what I was looking for, but still relevant. I was kind of looking for the other way around. But I figured out something else already